# Cassandra query stopped working after compaction

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I'm running Cassandra-2.0.4 using CQL3.

Before a recent compaction, I was able to query the following columnfamily with a WHERE clause on `accountid_name`. Suddenly that stopped returning results and after inserting a new row (with the same `accountid_name` I was querying before) it displays just the row that was added. Querying the entire table works as expected and displays all of the data.

Logs aren't showing any errors, the system has free memory, and the disk isn't full.

I'm running all of my test queries in cqlsh. Any ideas?

Relevant parts of the table follows:

```
CREATE TABLE segments (
  email text,
  accountid_name text,
  PRIMARY KEY (email, accountid_name)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

CREATE INDEX segments_accountid_name_idx ON segments (accountid_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

nodetool rebuild_index [keyspace] [columnfamily] [index_name]

Although -- according to a chat on IRC, losing the secondary index data is a bug, so hopefully this will be fixed soon.